# Asynchronous method has no availble extension methods, but resulting variable does have

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm createing some methods in a standard repository class using MongoDB with c# and async methods and I've stumbled upon some strange behaviour.

In the end it's probably not strange at all, rather the problem lies in my own inexperience with async programming.

Consider this code:

```
public async Task<T> GetItem<T>(ObjectId id) where T : BaseItemEntity
        {
            var col = GetTypedCollection<T>();

            var model = await col.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            return await model.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

Now that is totally fine, no compilation errors but I'm actually not sure its's correct calling await 2 times.

Now consider this code:

```
public async Task<T> GetItem<T>(ObjectId id) where T : BaseItemEntity
        {
            var col = GetTypedCollection<T>();

            var model = await col.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return model;
        }
```

Thats illegal according to the compiler. It's complaining about FirstOrDefaultAsync() not being an availble method to call. I would have to call .Result first to get access to .FirstOrDefaultAsync().

What is going on here?

Comment: because you are calling FirstOrDefaultAsync on a Task. Wrap parens around the first expression and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var model = await col.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Should be:

```
var model = await (await col.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This is because FindAsync returns a Task object, which FirstOrDefaultAsync doesn't work for. Awaiting the operation yields the actual result.

This is one of the most annoying things with async/await IMO, as it requires parentheses or variables to hold the awaited result for further processing.

Comment: '(await col.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();' again requires await before the parentheses if you want the object, else set ConfigureAwait(false).

Answer (score 1):

I think it actually should be

`var model = await (await col.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

both Async methods return a Task object, and Tasks don't have FirstOrDefault() method( this is why await in () is required). The other one is needed because this way model is your object and not a Task.